# PHP convert a SQL request into JSON

Tags: php, sql, json

I have a SQL table like this:

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE 
      config (ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
              nombre VARCHAR(50), 
              valor VARCHAR(50));";
```

Lets think it have this lines (ID,name,value) :

```
1 | name1 | value1
2 | name2 | value2
3 | name3 | value3
```

How i can convert the result of my SQL query into a JSON object which only contains name a value data?

Comment: SQL result will not be in string format. it may be an object or  an array.

Comment: you mean into _json string_? just fetch the rows like you normally would do, put it inside an array and use `json_encode` on it

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform three steps:

1.) Create the required SQL and run it:

```
$sql = "SELECT nombre, valor FROM config";
$stmt = $pdoCon->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

2.) Use your SQL-Connection (I will use PDO in my answer) to query the required data:

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

3.) Use `json_encode()` to create a JSON-String from the array:

```
$json = json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the data by executing the query that will return you an array then use json_encode to convert it into json

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try Below Code**
<?php
$sql="SELECT nombre, valor FROM config";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$myData=array(); // blank array
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        unset($row['nombre']);
       array_push($myData,$row); // push rows to array $myData
    }
} 

// get array with removed nombre ==>$myData

echo json_encode($myData); //get json

?>
```

Comment: Thanks Pedro Jose Otero Rodriguez  .