# PHP multi dimensional array SQL request to JSON

Tags: php, sql, json

Ok, this is a lot like my last question ([PHP convert a SQL request into JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50526144/php-convert-a-sql-request-into-json)) but im unable to find a solution even when it looks like it is very easy.

I have a very simple SQL table:

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE 
      example (ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
              name VARCHAR(50), 
              status VARCHAR(50),
              value VARCHAR(50));";
```

With the following values:

```
1 | name1 | open  | value1
2 | name2 | open  | value2
3 | name3 | close | value3
```

I call the desired data:

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM example where status='open'";
$result= mysqli_query($link,$sql);
$arrayofdata = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

Since $arrayofdata could have 1 or many arrays inside it, i try this:

```
$JSONED = json_encode($arrayofdata);
```

But the output value is very odd, and, i do not understands why, it do not includes the [] brackes (As far as i understands JSON format, [] should be first and last element on a JSON string)

I want a JSON object like this:

```
[{1,"name1","open","value1"},{2,"name2","open","value2"}]
```

Can it be done directly? Or must the code interact with $arrayofdata  to create a new array step by step?

Comment: You don't understand json format. See http://json.org.

Comment: The only thing off by your desired json, is that the inner arrays, would not have curly brackets, but square (since there are no keynames in those arrays). The issue you are seeing is due to what is actually returned from mysqli_fetch_array... which includes keynames by default (MYSQLI_BOTH)... and also only returns the first row (you have to loop it like in zhilevans example).

Answer (score 1):

you can get your desire results with something like the following code :

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM example where status='open'";
$result= mysqli_query($link,$sql);
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    //... maybe some processing of $row here ...

    $data[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: @PedroJoseOteroRodriguez you're welcome, good to hear , it works for you.